# Roaming Profiles in 2008 server

Tags: roaming-profile, roaming

On my 2008 Domain Controller I have set a roaming profile path for my user.  When i login, i get an info bubble saying that i am using a Temp Roaming profile. is this because of an issue with my profile path?

Comment: Check your event log, frequently there is more information there.  Post additional information, if present.

Answer (score 0):

There are a zillion reasons why you might get the "Temporary Profile" error, but most of them boil down to **"client cannot reach profile path"**.

If you're certain that the Active Directory account you're using has Full Control over the remote profile directory (both in NTFS ACLs *and* in the relevant network-share permissions), then the only thing left to do is to troubleshoot network connectivity. I'll bet there's a comprehensive guide for that sort of troubleshooting elsewhere on ServerFault.